# YA books about clones escaping from a facility and on the run

Tags: story-identification, books

YA trilogy. Read it around 2004-05. Random find at the library, don't know the publishing year.

The first book has 2 clones (male, age between 10-16) living in a very controlled environment but separate from each other. They eventually find out about each other and escape. Vaguely remember that the first book had a title like *Race Against Time*.

Second book title had something to do with the number 2; the title had something like the word "double" in it.

At some point in the series a third clone is found. There is also some sort of virtual reality and some characters in the VR who keep helping the clones. Vaguely remember this part in book 2 where one of the clones is going through a "tunnel of love" type place (not sure VR or reality) and at the end of it he meets a girl who helped him in the first book. Possible he has a crush on her too.

Also remember a line from the second book where someone says that the "clones standout too much because their faces are identical".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you remember what any of the covers looked like?  Check out other [ideas](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for things you could [edit] in to improve your question.

Comment: You might check out [this list](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Race+Against+Time&type=Fiction+Titles) though none of them seem likely.  It's not the Piers Anthony book, though it embarrasses me to admit I know that.

Comment: Some details match my question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247772/1980s-childrens-book-possibly-duology-about-cloned-boys but some do not. Putting the suggestion here in case it's a match.

Comment: Reminds me of [Duplik Jonas 7](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplik_Jonas_7) (roughly "Duplicate Jonas 7"), but some details are off. It's a German book, and single volume, so not worth posting as an answer I think.

Answer (score -1):

It reminds me of ***[Sharp North](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/546773.Sharp_North)*** (2005) by Patrick Cave, the first book in the *[Sharp North](https://www.goodreads.com/series/73059-sharp-north)* duology.

> In a futuristic world, will everyone be replaceable?
>
> Mira had always lived quietly until the day a stranger is shot and killed in front of her. The woman's body is quickly removed, leaving bloodstained snow and a crumpled piece of paper on the ground as the only clues to her murder. Mira discovers that the paper contains a list of names, including her own -- but why?
>
> Terrified, she begins to view everyone with suspicion, and attempts to follow the clues that the dead woman left behind, unaware of the danger she is stumbling into. For Mira lives in an environmentally damaged and socially dangerous Great Britain that is ruled by the caste of the Great Families, forming a society where reproduction is strictly limited and where families keep illegal clones -- or "spares" -- of themselves, just in case a replacement is ever needed...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The summaries and reviews I've found don't seem to match anything other than clones existing.