# 1980s children's book (possibly duology) about cloned boys

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, clones

What I remember:

- Published no later than 1990, probably more like 1985
- Near future setting, possibly featuring a vague Eastern/Western cold war scenario
- A boy of ~10 learns that he has a clone of the same age
- The clones secretly work together to ... do *something* that foils the plans of the adults who created them
- There may be a second book, where the boys learn there is a third clone
- The copy I read (US edition) was a slim hardcover of perhaps 150-200 pages
- Cover or dust jacket was primarily yellow
- Interior had some black-and-white illustrations, particularly on the end papers or near the title page

Any assistance locating this is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What country was this?  The U.K. often has different covers than the U.S., so that can help narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! US, edited accordingly.

Comment: Not [*The House of the Scorpion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_of_the_Scorpion)? It involves a clone boy, but not all the details fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kept poking around library catalogs and doing keyword searches and I found them! And archive.org has copies for the curious — [*Solution: Escape*](https://archive.org/details/solutionescape00coop) and [*Code Name: Clone*](https://archive.org/details/codenameclone00coop) by Margaret C. Cooper.

> In the 21st century, 13-year-old Stefan is sent to a scientific research station where his movements are closely monitored. He discovers he is a clone, destined to be part of a fanatical scheme to control the government

> In the future, cloned brothers Evonn and Stefan escape from behind the Iron Curtain to search for their father in the United States